# Bought additional iCloud space but it's not showing in Settings

Tags: iphone, icloud, storage

I just bought additional 50 GB of space in iCloud. I should mention that I had to change my credit card first because it was the first purchase in a while and the previous card expired. All went well. I received a security message from my ma bank, saying that my purchase went through, but when I checked in Settings, the available space still shows "0". I turned off the phone, still nothing. Anything else I can try? I wanted to sign out of iCloud as I saw some people being advised to do online, but I got a message that all my photos in iCloud library, drive, etc. will be removed from the iPhone. Unsure what exactly this means, I didn't risk it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you checked Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage and then under the second group of information that says ICLOUD / Total Storage / Available? Total Storage should say 50 GB and Available will depend on how you are using it.